# "They say that our uniform looks cool and easy to move."

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm not sure if the use of "easy to move" in this sentence is correct.

> They say that our uniform looks cool and easy to move.

It sounds strange to me. I can use the word "comfortable", but are there other words or ways to say it?

I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: That sentence seems fine, as applied to what looks like a comfortable uniform for hot-weather wear; but it could as easily applied to one that looks impressive and is easy to *sell.*

Comment: 'easy to move' means it is easy to take something and displace them (move them) from one place to another. If you want to say that when wearing these clothes, it is easy to move your arms and legs, you would say 'they are easy to move _in_'. This isn't a phrasal verb, it is just a dropping of referents. 'It is easy to move _myself_ in _these clothes_' (the other way is 'It is easy to move _the clothes_')

Answer (score 2):

***Comfortable***:

> (especially of clothes or furnishings) providing physical ease and relaxation.
>
> - ***comfortable*** sturdy shoes ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=comfortable%20meaning&sca_esv=558074753&ei=WDnfZKiZLYmThbIPk_mj-AM&oq=comfortable&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiC2NvbWZvcnRhYmxlKgIIBDILEAAYigUYsQMYkQIyBxAAGIoFGEMyBxAAGIoFGEMyCxAAGIoFGLEDGJECMgsQABiKBRixAxiRAjIHEAAYigUYQzIHEC4YigUYQzIHEAAYigUYQzIIEAAYgAQYsQMyCBAAGIAEGLEDSPgoUABYwRJwAHgBkAEAmAGRAqABvhOqAQUwLjMuOLgBAcgBAPgBAcICCBAAGIoFGJECwgIREC4YgAQYsQMYgwEYxwEY0QPCAgsQABiABBixAxiDAcICCxAuGIAEGLEDGIMBwgIOEC4YgAQYsQMYxwEY0QPCAhQQLhiKBRixAxiDARjHARjRAxiRAsICCxAuGIoFGLEDGIMBwgIKEAAYigUYsQMYQ-IDBBgAIEGIBgE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp))

It's not uncommon to describe clothing as *looking cool and comfortable*.

I have seen clothing described as *[clothes that are easy to move in](https://www.clarasunwoo.com/blogs/fashion-tips/i-only-wear-clothes-that-are-easy-to-move-in-heres-why)*, which may be more precise, but can be ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Can I also describe clothes as "activity-friendly "?

Comment: I would think a community or environment is activity-friendly, not clothes.

Comment: I understand. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I upvoted the answer but then had to downvote because of "is a bit of a mouthful". What is the difficulty with "clothes that are easy to move in"? It's perfectly grammatical and would "roll off the tongue" of a native speaker. The downvote arrow doesn't set the counter to zero, but to negative one. Also, **easy to move in** is not more precise, but has an entirely different meaning from **easy to move**.  Just figured out the voting arrow. You're back to zero.

Comment: @Tim I have edited. I probably meant "wordy" in comparison with the one word "comfortable". Also, I said "more precise" in relation to "comfortable" not in relation to "easy to move", which indeed, has a different meaning altogether (the uniform itself is easy to move).

Comment: Now **comfortable**, that does give native speakers trouble :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple typo. The phrase should be *easy to move **in***. The *in* is required.

Clothes don't move by themselves, but people have to move in the clothes.
Some clothes are difficult to move in, others are easy to move it. It depends on the movements involved and the construction of the clothes (and whether they fit, but we're idealizing here).

The original source S is something like

- *For `Indef` to move in the clothes is easy*,
  which becomes, by Extraposition
- *It is easy for `Indef` to move in the clothes*
  and that becomes
- *The clothes are easy for `Indef` to move in.*

That's why the *in* is necessary; it's in the original and nothing deletes it.

Comment: +1 Is the *it* a typo in *Clothes ... it*?